# Resolved! sequential order from html inserted into php

Tags: php, html, sql-order-by, sequential

Hoping someone is able to assist.

I have a php file that I needs to add some sequential order to, as the numbers are mixed around, eg: (5,6,7,15,16,17,8,9..) I'm strugling to find the correct manner on how to add the code to the following piece in the below php echoed from the html.

the <option value='".$row2['section_id']."'> is the part that needs to be set to sequential order

```
<?php 
$sectionList = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM dance_section_types");
   while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sectionList)) { 
      echo "<option value='".$row2['section_id']."'>".$row2['section_name']."</option>";
   }
?>
</select>
```

this is the incorrect order that keeps being pulled through via html:

```
<select name="section" id="section" required="">
<option value="2" selected="">Festival: Straight Solo</option>
<option>---</option>
<option value="1">Festival: Studio set Solo</option>
<option value="2">Festival: Straight Solo</option>
<option value="3">Festival: Duet/Trio</option>
<option value="4">Festival: Pas de Deux</option>
<option value="5">Festival: Group</option>
<option value="6">Festival: Formation</option>
<option value="7">Festival: Production</option>
<option value="15">Festival &amp; Competition: Studio set Solo</option>
<option value="16">Festival &amp; Competition: Straight Solo</option>
<option value="17">Festival &amp; Competition: Duet/Trio</option>
<option value="8">Competition: Studio set Solo</option>
<option value="9">Competition: Straight Solo</option>
<option value="10">Competition: Duet/Trio</option>
<option value="11">Competition: Pas de Deux</option>
<option value="12">Competition: Group</option>
<option value="13">Competition: Formation</option>
<option value="14">Competition: Production</option>
<option value="18">Festival &amp; Competition: Pas de Deux</option>
<option value="19">Festival &amp; Competition: Group</option>
<option value="20">Festival &amp; Competition: Formation</option>
<option value="21">Festival &amp; Competition: Production</option>
</select>
```

this is the correct order and how it should display on html, once the php has been set:

```
<select name="section" id="section" required="">
<option value="2" selected="">Festival: Straight Solo</option>
<option>---</option>
<option value="1">Festival: Studio set Solo</option>
<option value="2">Festival: Straight Solo</option>
<option value="3">Festival: Duet/Trio</option>
<option value="4">Festival: Pas de Deux</option>
<option value="5">Festival: Group</option>
<option value="6">Festival: Formation</option>
<option value="7">Festival: Production</option>
<option value="8">Competition: Studio set Solo</option>
<option value="9">Competition: Straight Solo</option>
<option value="10">Competition: Duet/Trio</option>
<option value="11">Competition: Pas de Deux</option>
<option value="12">Competition: Group</option>
<option value="13">Competition: Formation</option>
<option value="14">Competition: Production</option>
<option value="15">Festival &amp; Competition: Studio set Solo</option>
<option value="16">Festival &amp; Competition: Straight Solo</option>
<option value="17">Festival &amp; Competition: Duet/Trio</option>
<option value="18">Festival &amp; Competition: Pas de Deux</option>
<option value="19">Festival &amp; Competition: Group</option>
<option value="20">Festival &amp; Competition: Formation</option>
<option value="21">Festival &amp; Competition: Production</option>
</select>
```

After adding the following ORDER BY as suggested below:
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM dance_section_types ORDER BY section_id

to the code below:

```
<select name="section" id="section" required>
<option value="<?php echo $row['section_id']; ?>" selected ><?php echo $row['section_name']; ?></option>
<option>---</option>
<?php 
$sectionList = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM dance_section_types ORDER BY section_id");
   while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sectionList)) { 
      echo "<option value='".$row2['section_id']."'>".$row2['section_name']."</option>";
   }
?>
</select>
```

and checking my webpage, it stated the following:
This page isn’t working
dance.artisticulta.co.za is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

---

The problem is resolved, thank you!

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM dance_entries WHERE entry_id = '$entryID' ORDER BY **section_id ASC**"; $resid = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); $id = mysqli_fetch_array($resid,MYSQLI_ASSOC); $checkId = $id['studio_id'];;`

the "section_id ASC" in bold above was named "column_name(s)" which was incorrect, this was replaced with the correct name

Comment: You've tagged the question with `sql-order-by`, have you tried using an `ORDER BY` clause in your SQL code?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM dance_section_types ORDER BY section_id`

Comment: @MarkusZeller  ORDER BY was added to PHP, but it broke the page...   `Section:<br/>
<select name="section" id="section" required>
<option value="<?php echo $row['section_id']; ?>" selected ><?php echo $row['section_name']; ?></option>
<option>---</option>
<?php 
$sectionList = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM dance_section_types ORDER BY section_id");
   while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sectionList)) { 
      echo "<option value='".$row2['section_id']."'>".$row2['section_name']."</option>";
   }
?>`

Comment: What does "broke the page" mean? Please update the question, the code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I have updated the very top descrition

Comment: An error 500 is mostly a PHP problem. Look into the logs or use `ini_set('display_errors', true);` on a develop system (AVOID printing errors on a production system!). Execute the query in your DBMS to see if the query is ok and what it does result.